# Get latitude and longitude to textbox1 and textbox2 from selected city in dropdownlist through google map api in c# webforms asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need to get latitude and longitude to `textbox1` and `textbox2` from selected city in dropdownlist through google map api. Im using C# and ASP .NET Web Forms.

Here's the code i tried:

```
function sayHello()
{

    string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=+Dropdownlist1.Text+Dropdownlist2.Text+Dropdownlist3.Text+&sensor=false");
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {

     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
     {

       string address = document.getElementById(reader).ToString;
       float latitude;
       float longitude;

       //var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
       longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();


       document.getElementById("TextBox1").Text = latitude;
       document.getElementById("TextBox2").Text = longitude;

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you make a call to get google maps geocoder json response:

```
    string json = string.Empty;
    string url = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address));
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

You have to remember to encode your address string, which might contain some illegal characters, which cannot be used in querystring.

Geocoder response is in json format and you can parse it by yourself or use some tools designed for that. In my working fiddle I created a few c# classes based on json response (using [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/#)):

```
public class Location
{
    public double lat
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double lng
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class GeocodeResponse
{
    public List<Result> results
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then I deserialized json response to GeocodeResponse using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) JSON Serializer.

```
GeocodeResponse gr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeocodeResponse>(json);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("lat: {0}, long: {1}", gr.results[0].geometry.location.lat, gr.results[0].geometry.location.lng));
```

You can try working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IYAMEm) for this. It's console app, but I believe you can quickly convert it to your webform app.